# Быстрый способ межпроцессных коммуникаций на одном ПК?

Tags: java, производительность, ipc

У меня есть два jar процесса не связанные друг с другом, которые **находятся на одном ПК**. В одной из них мне нужно систематически получать объекты находящиеся в другой.

Для этого я пробовал использовать сокеты(UDP/TCP), результатом не доволен, так как при больших нагрузках (около 1000 запросов в сек) некоторые запросы/ответы теряются или не успевают считываться. Плюс ко всему они работают медленно. В среднем один запрос занимает от **0.3мс** до **1.5мс** (с ростом кол-ва запросов время также растёт).

Размер запросов до **1кб**, размер ответов(сериализованных объектов) до **8кб**.

В идеале я бы хотел брать данные прямо из соседней программы обычным методом `.get(имя объекта)`, который бы возвращал мне объект, но, к сожалению, сделать эти процессы дочерним/родительским невозможно.

Насколько я понимаю сокеты в основном предназначены для коммуникаций по сети, отсюда и не максимальная скорость на localhost'e, но у меня всё  на одном компьютере, поэтому я думаю, что есть способ более быстрой передачи данных.

Также необходимо, чтобы это не было зависимостью от сторонних проектов. (Не считая Netty, но насколько я знаю все коммуникации Netty основаны на сокетах, поэтому вряд ли он поможет)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680898/communication-between-two-separate-java-desktop-applications

Comment: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue обещают 1 микросекунду. Еще есть https://github.com/pcdv/jocket ну и MappedByteBuffer

Comment: ¿1000 запросов в секунду с передачей аж до 9 МБ данных? Вот это большие нагрузки, не каждый суперкомпьютер справится!

Comment: @user7860670 Если это не сарказм - то сомневаюсь что 9мб данных в секунду - большая проблема для современного железа. А если это сарказм то в чем смысл вашего комментария?

Comment: Так это вы жалуетесь, что не можете заставить приложение работать при таких "больших нагрузках"...

Comment: @user7860670 я лишь сделал вывод, что если сокеты не справляются с 1000 запросами - то для них это большая нагрузка.

Comment: Тут скорее надо было сделать вывод, что это в вашей программе какие-то проблемы, потому что другие приложения спокойно справляются с на порядок более высокой нагрузкой, даже когда работают через нормальную сеть, а не в пределах одной машины.

Comment: @user7860670 Тем не менее суть темы - найти альтернативу сокетам, которая будет быстрее и это четко изложено. Скорость не единственный минус сокетов  для меня. Поэтому я создал тему для поиска альтернатив сокетам, а не помощи в реализации сокетов.